# Prevent rotation on embedded YouTube videos

Tags: objective-c, swift, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, ytplayerview

I have a `UIViewController` which basically only runs in a landscape mode.
This `UIViewController` has a `UIView` that inherits `YTPlayerView` to play YouTube videos in it.

As described, the `UIViewController` never goes to portrait mode. However, when the device in portrait mode, the YouTube video iFrame rotate to portrait mode while the `UIViewController` is in landscape mode.

To better visualize this, see the screenshot below:

[image]

**My question is:** How should I prevent the video from rotating in non-landscape mode?

*Note: The only time the video goes portrait mode is when the video is playing.*

Comment: Have you found any solution, I have same problem, I want to lock video in landscape mode.